# "undefined" is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm getting this error in my console. the last thing I did was registering a user! now I'm getting this error, I don't know why! I think it says that "user" is not a valid JSON how come? where I went wrong!

```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>     at ./src/context/Context.js (Context.js:5:1)
>     at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
>     at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
>     at ./src/components/topbar/TopBar.jsx (SideMenu.jsx:23:1)
>     at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
>     at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
>     at ./src/App.js (return-arrow.svg:26:1)
```

**`Context.js` Where the error is. See const INITIAL_STATE**

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import Reducer from "./Reducer";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};

export const Context = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);
export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
  }, [state.user]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Context `Actions.js` the same goes for login and it worked fine**

```
export const RegisterStart = (userCredentials) => ({
  type: "REGISTER_START",
});

export const RegisterSuccess = (user) => ({
  type: "REGISTER_SUCCESS",
  payload: user,
});

export const RegisterFailure = () => ({
  type: "REGISTER_FAILURE",
});
```

**The function in Register page**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "REGISTER_START" });
    setError(false);
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/register", {
        username,
        email,
        password,
        repeatPassword,
      });
      dispatch({ type: "REGISTER_SUCCESS", payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "REGISTER_FAILURE" });
      setError(true);
    }
  };
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("user")` is returning `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

For me I was getting this issue in bizarre way even though I check if there is an item but still getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON` and this because the local storage value was the string `"undefined"` rather then `undefined` it self that is why the condition `if(item)` was always verified. to fix this I had to check also that `item!=="undefied"`

```js
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    const localStorageValue = window.localStorage.getItem(key)
    if (localStorageValue && localStorageValue !== 'undefined') {
      return JSON.parse(localStorageValue)
    }
    return typeof intialValue === 'function' ? intialValue() : intialValue
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no "user" entry in `localStorage` at the point of running this code.
Therefor, it throws an error since you are trying to `JSON.parse` an `undefined` value.

To make this work, we can check if "user" exists in `localStorage` before trying to parse it.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: localStorage.getItem("user") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) : null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};
```

What we do here is first check if the return value of `localStorage.getItem("user")` is truthy and therefor not `undefined`.

If you want to be more explicit, you can also write it as -

```
user: localStorage.getItem("user") !== undefined ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) : null,
```

Comment: thank you for answering. It didn't work!! why it's returning undefined?

Comment: WDYM it didn't work? Does it still throw the same error?

Comment: Also, when trying to do `localStorage.getItem` on an item that doesn't yet exist in the storage, the return value would be undefined. That's likely why you have this issue.

Comment: ye, it still throw the same error

Comment: This is strange and might mean that your problem lies elsewhere. Please provide a reproducible example via the likes of [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-mountain-e5t9d4?file=/src/context/Context.js here you have it

Comment: the whole app is using useContext ! I don't why all of a sudden it stopped!

Comment: This is not reproducible. When you provide an example, you need to make sure it actually works, otherwise it's not much of an example.

Comment: just delete the "EXIST" NAME OF localstorge then the code is run

Answer (score 0):

Your initial state is returning undefined initially because you are yet to set the item `user`.
You can first check if `user` exist in localStorage: yes => return user else, return a default value of null

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: localStorage.getItem("user") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
  isFetching: false,
 error: false,
};
```

Comment: thank you for answering. It didn't work!! why it's returning undefined?

Answer (score 0):

The initial state should be set as null only, you are not fetching anythng from the local storage. Check the code below

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};
```

Answer (score -1):

try replacing:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};
```

by:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: localStorage.getItem("user")? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) : null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};
```

Comment: thank you for answering. It didn't work!! why it's returning undefined?

Comment: same error at same line ?

Comment: yes, it throws the same error at the same line

Comment: before the INITIAL_STATE can you add console.log(localStorage.getItem("user")) and show me the result ?

Comment: it returns "undefined"

Comment: please have a look here https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-mountain-e5t9d4?file=/src/context/Context.js

Comment: did you try the localStorage.getItem("user") !== undefined?  on the other answer?

Comment: yes i tried all the answers, but it stays the same

Comment: The js statement  condition? if yes : else    always go to else if the condition is undefined, so the only way I see is that the code didn't take that modification, try reopening your coding sowftware or clearing cache somewhere

Comment: JSON.parse('undefined')

Answer (score -2):

So I cleared the browser cache and it worked fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).